# Problem with Conv2DTranspose layer in FCN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I'm trying to implement FCN with keras, but when I tried to upsample the feature map I got a problem. The size of feature map after upsample doesn't has the same as the input size. I found that this problem happened because of the size of feature map is odd and after pooling layer the size of it is devided by 2.

For example: with input size (95,95,3) with 3 is number of channel, after I apply max pooling the size will be (47,47,3). So when I try to upsample the feature map x2 then the shape will be (94,94,3)....

Comment: Looks like the size doesn't register decimals. which makes sense because you cannot have a half pixel. perhaps it's better to not have odd numbers when you're dividing by 2.

Comment: I think that we can not make sure that the size will not be odd when pass it through many max pooling layer. But I think we could crop the size after upsampling it. Maybe it is the solution for this problem. I have just read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117302/upsampling-in-semantic-segmentation?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use padding in order to solve your problem.

If, at a point during your downsampling you reach an odd number, then by means of plain upsampling/transposed convolution you will not maintain the height and width of the input image.

The solution is padding; have a look at this documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding2D

Practically, when you downsample with a factor of 2 and you get an odd number (54/2 = 27), you get the size (27,27), and by means of ZeroPadding2D you can resize the image to (28,28) for example.

Applying padding at each step where you encounter this 'odd number' problem will help you solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help... By the way, if I use cropping2D, will it affect the performance of the model?

Comment: No. It would be the inverse of ZeroPadding in your case (from 27 to 26 instead of from 27 to 28)